# Showing the norm decreases then increases when going through the origin

Tags: real-analysis, curves, differential

I have this analysis problem:

"Let $\gamma:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^p$ be a curve which passes through the origin in $\mathbb R^p$ at a
point where its velocity vector is non-zero (that is, assume $\gamma(t_0)=0$ and $\gamma'(t_0)\neq0$ at some point $t_0\in\mathbb R$). Prove that there is an interval $I$ centered
at $t_0$ such that $\Vert\gamma(t)\Vert$ is decreasing for $t<t_0$ and increasing for $t>t_0$. Hint: $\Vert\gamma\Vert$ is increasing (decreasing) wherever $\Vert\gamma\Vert^2=\gamma\cdot\gamma$ is increasing (decreasing)."

I can't quite seem to get through it. It's clear that since $\Vert\gamma\Vert$ (and $\gamma\cdot\gamma$) takes on only nonnegative values that it should decrease then increase if the value is ever 0 (like it would be at $t_0$) presuming the function is relatively well-behaved. It's just ensuring that this function is that well-behaved that I'm having troubles with. Should I be making some assumptions about $\gamma$, such as that it's continuously differentiable or something?

Comment: For a counterexample take Hagen von Eitzen's answer to [Differentiable at a point with positive derivative implies increasing in neighborhood of point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2768994/differentiable-at-a-point-with-positive-derivative-implies-increasing-in-neighbo).  Under the additional assumption of continuous differentiability the statement appears to be true (however its proof is rather not very straightforward).

Comment: Honestly, what's getting me is how do I deal with the possibility that the function has infinitely many turning points in any neighborhood of $t_0$? And in that regard, I'm realising there seems to be an issue with something this text said, that you can always eliminate crossing points from a curve by restricting the domain. This doesn't seem to be true in a case like what I mentioned where the curve might pass through a given point infinitely often in any neighborhood of any value that maps to that point.

Comment: Functions that are differentiable only can be extremely wild, see the MO discussion [Everywhere differentiable function that is nowhere monotonic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167323/everywhere-differentiable-function-that-is-nowhere-monotonic).

Comment: I noticed in that discussion that the poster said that it's clear that there are intervals on which a function is monotone provided the function is continuously differentiable, but I don't quite see how one would show that

Comment: If a function is $C^1$ on an interval then either its derivative is constantly equal to zero (so the function is constant) or its derivative is somewhere negative (say for definiteness).  By the $C^1$ property, the derivative is negative on some subinterval.  And on that subinterval, the function is (strictly) decreasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in one of my comments, even in the case of $\gamma$ being continuously differentiable the proof is not so straightforward, so I decided to give it here.

Assume that the curve $\gamma$ as in the question is of class $C^1$.  We have
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(\gamma(t) \cdot \gamma(t)) = 2 \gamma'(t) \cdot \gamma(t)
$$
for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.  The problem reduces to finding the sign of
$$
\gamma'(t) \cdot \gamma(t)
$$
for $t$ close to $t_0$, $t \ne t_0$.  Using the [integral form of the mean value theorem for vector-valued functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions) we can write 
$$
\gamma(t) = (t - t_0) \Bigl( \int\limits_{0}^1 \gamma'(t_0 + s(t-t_0))\, ds \Bigr),
$$
so
$$
\gamma'(t) \cdot \gamma(t) = (t - t_0) \Bigl( \gamma'(t) \cdot \int\limits_{0}^1 \gamma'(t_0 + h(t-t_0))\, dh \Bigr)
$$
for $t$ close to $t_0$.  The inner product
$$
\gamma'(t) \cdot \int\limits_{0}^1 \gamma'(t_0 + h(t-t_0))\, dh 
$$
at $t_0$ equals $\lVert \gamma'(t_0)\rVert^2 > 0$, therefore it follows from the $C^1$ property of $\gamma$ that it is positive for $t$ belonging to some neighborhood of $t_0$.  This completes the proof.