# Part of a proof of a theorem about pseudoconvex

Tags: convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

This is from Nonlinear programming Bazaraa:
Would you please explain why the marked part is correct?

[image]

Comment: @Benjamin Actually I thought about that but I thought I was wrong. How is it the mean value theorem?

Comment: I'm sorry for the misleading comment. I added a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

We make use of the following lemma, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3582247/810273) for a proof.

> If $I$ is an interval, $x_0\in I$ and $f:I\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable with $f'(x_0)>0$, then there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f(x)>f(x_0)$ for all $x\in(x_0,x_0+\varepsilon)$.

**Short answer to the question.**
Note that $\nabla f(x')^t(x_2-x')$ is the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $x_2-x'$ at the point $x'$. Hence, there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that the function $\mu\mapsto f((1-\mu) x'+\mu x_2)$ takes values larger than $f(x')$ for all $\mu\in(0,\varepsilon)$. This implies the statement.

**More details on the directional derivative.** Let $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ with $g(\mu)=f((1-\mu) x'+\mu x_2)$. By the chain rule, $g$ is differentiable and satisfies $g'(0)=\nabla f(x')^t(x'-x_2)>0$. Hence, above lemma implies there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $g(\mu)>g(0)$ for all $\mu\in(0,\varepsilon)$. Choosing any $\mu\in(0,\varepsilon)\cap(0,1)$ and setting $\hat x = \mu x_2 + (1-\mu)x'$ then yields the desired value $\hat x$.