# Monotonicity of a Function to increase or decrease about a point

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, monotone-functions

I am currently studying increasing and decreasing tendency of a function when I came across the following example,

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}x & \text{if }x< 4 \\ 5 & \text{if } x = 4 \\ 10-x & \text{if} x>4 \end{cases}.$$

I want to know whether the function is increasing or decreasing about the point $x=4$.

Now by the [definition](https://math.fel.cvut.cz/mt/txtb/3/txe3ba3e.htm#:%7E:text=Given%20a%20function%20f%20and,values%20with%20f%20(a)) of pointwise monotonicity $$\space \text{(i.e. $f$ is increasing about $x=a$ if $f(a-h)<f(a)<f(a+h)$ )}$$

I found that for sufficiently small $h$ this condition is satisfied by the function. But my teacher insists that to determine the tendency of a function about a point we have to consider the tendency after the point and before the point. Since after $x=4, f$ is decreasing and before $x=4, f$ is increasing hence it is neither increasing nor decreasing about $x=4$. I find this statement paradoxical because again to find tendency after the point $x=a$ we have to consider even more points (say $x=a±e$) and find tendency about those but to do that we have to find tendency after and before those points as well.

The questions I have are:-

$1$. What is the tendency of $f$ about $x=4$

$2$. Is the argument given by the teacher correct?

$3$. What is the true definition of increasing function (in case I have the wrong one)

Comment: Have you looked at the graph of the function? Does it really make sense to say that it's increasing at $x=4$? I think the definition you give for increasing is fine for continuous functions, not so useful otherwise.

Comment: Yes the graph is the trickiest part. If I consider a very small interval say [3.999,4.001] and evaluate f at the boundary points then it seems to be increasing

Comment: But if you actually **look** at the graph (or just think about the formula), you'll see that from, say, $4.0001$ to $4.001$ it's decreasing, right?

Comment: It is decreasing in [4.0001,4.001] but we're talking about the point x=4 so that should be irrelevant

Comment: @QuiGonnJinn "*by the definition of increasing function*" $\;-\;$ Please quote the source and the full definition that you are using. Monotonicity must be defined on a subset of the domain, it cannot be defined at a single point. (And there is no interval around $x=4$ on which the function is increasing.)

Comment: @dxiv: *Monotonicity must be defined on a subset of the domain, it cannot be defined at a single point.* --- [Pointwise monotonicity notions are widely used in analysis!](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22monotone+at+a+point%22&filter=0)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro You are right of course, and I phrased it rather carelessly. What I meant is that (in the context of this question, in particular) talking about (something that sounds like) pointwise monotonicity without other stipulations would be normally understood as local monotonicity (over a neighborhood). The OP has not clarified yet what the wider context is of the definition they quoted.

Comment: @dxiv https://math.fel.cvut.cz/mt/txtb/3/txe3ba3e.htm#:~:text=Given%20a%20function%20f%20and,values%20with%20f%20(a).

Comment: @QuiGonnJinn Thanks for the link. That defines (a certain kind of) *pointwise* monotonicity, which is not necessarily understood as "*the definition of increasing function*" in general. It would help your question if you edited the post and clarified that. Also, are you sure your teacher is using the same definition?

Comment: @dxiv: For what it's worth, the phrase "about a point" is poorly chosen, because this suggests the behavior exists in a neighborhood of the point, which is not what the OP is dealing with. Indeed, the notion of pointwise increase/decrease I thought the question involved is little used and I was sufficiently curious to click on the question. Then, as I was reading the question, I realized that "at a point" is actually intended.

Comment: I just made a quick sketch of the function. The function is increasing at $x=4$ (your definition is missing a quantifier aspect -- there exists $h>0$ such that $\ldots)$ and increasing at each point less than $4$ and decreasing at each point greater than $4.$ For pointwise monotonicity notions, it is incorrect to argue as your teacher is doing. Indeed, your teacher's argument is assuming a kind of continuity behavior for pointwise monotonicity behavior that doesn't exist, in a similar way that [this doesn't exist for derivatives at a point](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2768994/13130).