# Differential at zero greater than zero implies increasing in an open interval with zero as infimum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, monotone-functions

[Differentiable at a point with positive derivative implies increasing in neighborhood of point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2768994/1177828)

Answer to the above question is false and it's disproven with the example given by @Hagen von Eitzen.
However later @Yibo Yang commented that a weaker statement holds ( https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3582247/1177828 ).

My doubt is that the statement by @Yibo Yang can also be disproven by @Hagen von Eitzen example, right ? For every $\delta >0$ we can find $n$ such that $\frac{1}{2n\pi}<\delta$. Then $f'(\frac{1}{2n\pi})< 0$. So function is not increasing in $(0,\delta)$ for any $\delta >0$.

I felt like I did something wrong, but where ?

Comment: Double check the weaker statement you're questioning. It doesn't say that $f$ is increasing in a neighborhood of $x_0$.

Comment: Yes. But it says it is increasing in $(x_0,x_0+\delta)$ which also contains $\frac{1}{2n\pi}$ for some $n$. So function is not increasing in that interval also.

Comment: No, it just says the values of $f$ in that region are larger than $f(x_0)$.

Comment: I understood what it says. But if there is a point $k \in (x_0,x_0+\delta)$ such that $f'(k)<0$, then function cannot be in creasing in whole $(x,x+\delta)$, right?

Comment: Right, that's the definition of increasing. But Yibo's statement says nothing about $f$ being increasing on an interval.

Comment: Yibo's statement is "However, a weaker statement holds: if $f$ is differentiable at a limit point $x_0$ with positive derivative $f'(x_0) > 0$, then there exists a small neighborhood to the right of $x_0$ that all have higher function value than $f(x_0)$, i.e., $\exists \delta >0, \forall x \in (x_0, x_0 + \delta), f(x) > f(x_0)$."

Comment: That is there exist a neighborhood to the right of $x_0$ (which is also an interval, right ?) in which function is increasing

Comment: No. Where are you getting "increasing"? The statement is just that $f(x)>f(x_0)$ for every $x$ in the interval. $x_0$ is fixed. "Increasing" would mean $f(x)<f(y)$ for every $x,y$ in the interval with $x<y$.

Comment: Oh yes. Got it thanks